# Azure AD wildcard in middle((not at the end or begging)) of reply url not working

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I want to add wildcard in middle of reply URL but it doesn't work.
For example :
I have the following url that reply to redirection from Azure AD.

**https://example.com/backoffice/en_US/USD/ProcessLogin**

There are different URLs for each local and currency combination, so I want to use wildcards

I tried different wildcard combinations but none of the following reply URLs worked

```
https://example.com/backoffice/*/ProcessLogin

https://example.com/backoffice/**/ProcessLogin

https://example.com/backoffice/*/*/ProcessLogin
```

it starts working when I put wildcard at the end of the URL. but I don't want to add wildcard to end of the URL.

```
https://example.com/backoffice/*
```

is there a trick to make it work? or only wildcard at end or beginning supported?

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're trying to do, it seems you are correct that it doesn't seem to like * in the middle, but this goes to a slightly different issue. if possible you should avoid using wildcards in the reply/redirect urls as it creates some security risk.

the better way would be to either store the location in a cookie and use the previous location as a call back like https://joonasw.net/view/avoiding-wildcard-reply-urls-with-msal-js

or as suggested at the bottom of this article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url
should use a state parameter.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I know it creates security issue when you add wildcard at the begging  or at the end of the URL but i couldn't find any article that said about security issue when you put at the middle. I think if oath provider support regex reply URL nobody will face any issue.