# How to use wildcard inside domain name in Redirect URIs (Azure AD)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, prometheus, grafana

There have been some questions regarding this issue on StackOverflow, but none of them have a well-defined answer.

I am trying to enable SSO authentication with Azure AD for Grafana. My Grafana domains look like this:

```
monitoring.cluster1.company.com
monitoring.cluster2.company.com
monitoring.cluster3.company.com
```

I have a couple hundred of these.

In the app manifest, I tried setting up redirect URIs in multiple ways:

```
https://*.company.com/login/azuread -> does not match my URL
https://monitoring.*.company.com/login/azuread -> Azure does not accept it
```

Is there really any way to circumvent this? I read about a solution involving cookies, but I  honestly did not understand how that works or how it can be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** that: Azure AD supports redirect URL of wildcard type **`https://*.xxx.com`** but not `https://xxx.*.abc.com` type. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#restrictions-on-wildcards-in-redirect-uris).

I created an Azure AD Application and tried to add r**edirect URL** as `https://monitoring.*.company.com/login/azuread` .

And got the error like below:

[image]

As a workaround you have to update the redirect URL as **`https://*.company.com/login/azuread`**

[image]

- Due to security issues, wildcard URIs should be avoided.
- A redirection endpoint URI must be an absolute URI according to OAuth 2.0 specification.
- **Otherwise**, if you want to add `https://monitoring.*.company.com/login/azuread` as redirect URL you have to add manually as

`https://monitoring.cluster1.company.com/login/azuread https://monitoring.cluster2.company.com/login/azuread`

**Reference:**

[Azure AD wildcard in middle((not at the end or beginning)) of reply url not working - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615883/azure-ad-wildcard-in-middlenot-at-the-end-or-begging-of-reply-url-not-workin) by alphaz18

Comment: In the end, I have changed the Grafana URL to https://*.company.com. Couldn't make it work otherwise.